# Neo4J - Query will not terminate. Results in `out of memory` error. Recursive problem?

Tags: recursion, neo4j

I'm trying to delete based on a child-parent relationship. My query will not terminate. Why? Recursion issue? The result is an out of memory error.

```
MATCH (c: itemContainer)<-[:HAS_VERSION]-(cv: itemContainerVersion {uuid: "$ID", version: 1})-[wfr]->(wf: workflowState)
WITH c, cv, wfr
DELETE wfr
WITH c, cv
MATCH (parent)-[*0..]-(child)
WHERE (parent)--(cv)-[:HAS_VERSION]->(c)
WITH DISTINCT parent, child, cv, c
MATCH (child)-[cvr]-(n)--(cv2: itemContainerVersion)
WITH parent, child, cv, c, cvr, n, cv2
    FOREACH(i IN CASE WHEN exists((child)-[cvr]-(n)--(cv2: itemContainerVersion)) THEN [1] ELSE [] END | DELETE cvr)
    FOREACH(i IN CASE WHEN NOT exists((child)-[cvr]-(n)--(cv2: itemContainerVersion)) THEN [1] ELSE [] END | DETACH DELETE child)
DETACH DELETE parent, cv
RETURN parent, child, cv
```

Comment: This is what's killing your query: `MATCH (parent)-[*0..]-(child) WHERE (parent)--(cv)-[:HAS_VERSION]->(c)`. It's getting all possible paths in the graph, and only after it finds all of them (and you might have millions of matches or more, multiplied out by the number of rows you had previously for c/cv), only after, will it filter according to your WHERE clause. I think you really need to give us a textual and in-depth description of what you're really trying to do in this, as I'm positive it isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: I'm trying to delete every node and relationship in the graph without a specific couple of paths. I want to do it this way without explicitly defining each possible path so that if new node types are added in the future, the query does not have to be updated to delete the new node types. I'll add a better description to the question soon